# Search for a pattern in a file

Tags: regex, perl, file-io

I have a file `eg.txt` with contents of this sort :

```
....text...
....text...
COMP1 = ../../path1/path2/path3
COMP2 = ../../path4/path5/path6
```

and so on, for a large number of application names (the "COMP"s). I need to get the path -- the stuff including and after the second slash -- for a user-specified application.

This is the code I've been trying :

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $line = "";
my $app  = "";

print "Enter the app";
$app = <STDIN>;
print $app;

open my $fh, '<', "eg.txt" or die "Cannot open $!";

while (<$fh>) {
    $line = <$fh>;
    if ( $line && $line =~ /($app)( = )(..\/)(..)(.*)/ ) {
        print $5;
    }
}
```

This prints the name of the user-input application, and does nothing else. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Don't forget to [`chomp`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html) the newline off your `$app`.

Comment: Ah yes, a very silly error - thanks a ton for pointing it out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two main problems with your program

- The `$app` variable contains a newline at the end from the enter key you pressed when you typed it in. That will prevent the pattern from matching so you need to use `chomp` to remove it. The same applies to lines read from your file
- The `<$fh>` in your `while` statement reads a line from your file into the default variable `$_`, and then `$line = <$fh>` reads another, so you are ignoring alternate lines from the file

Here is a version of your program that I think should work although I am unable to test it at present. I have dropped your `$line` variable altogether and hope that doesn't confuse you. `$_` is the default variable for the pattern match so it isn't mentioned explicitly anywhere

```
use strict;
use warnings;

print "Enter the app: ";
my $app = <STDIN>;
chomp $app;

open my $fh, '<', 'eg.txt' or die "Cannot open: $!";

while ( <$fh> ) {
    if ( /$app\s*=\s*(.+)/ ) {
        my $path = $1;
        $path =~ s/.*\.\.//;
        print $path, "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: That's perfect. Thank you! I can't believe I made an error as silly as skipping every other line.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The input did not matched in regex because newlines were coming along with them, so better use `chomp` to trim them. In while loop you are displacing two times the file handle, I don't know why. So after corrections this should work:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $line = "";
my $app = "";

print "Enter the app";
chomp($app = <STDIN>);
print "$app: ";

open my $fh, '<', "eg.txt" or die "Cannot open $!";

while($line = <$fh>)
{
    chomp $line;
    if($line && $line =~ /($app)( = )(..\/)(..)(.*)/)  
    {
        print "$5 \n";
    }
}
close($fh);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing `<$fh>` twice in your loop. This will have the effect of interpreting only every other line. You might want to change the top of the loop to something like this:

```
while (defined(my $line = <$fh>)) {
```

and remove the `my $line ...` at the top of the program.

Also, you might want to consider chomping your input line so that you don't have to think about the trailing newline character:

```
while (defined(my $line = <$fh>)) {
    chomp $line;
```

Your regular expression is also a bit dicey. You probably want to bind it to the beginning and end of the search space and escape the literal dots. You may also want `$app` to be interpreted as a string rather than a regexp, which can be done by wrapping it with `\Q...\E`. Also unless your file format specifies single spaces around the equals, I'd be tempted to make those flexible to zero or more occurrences. Also, if you aren't going to use the earlier captures, I would say don't do them, so:

```
if ($line && $line =~ /^\Q$app\E *= *\.\.\/\.\.(.*)$/)
{
    print $1;
```

(Some may say you should use `\A` and `\z` rather than `^` and `$`. That choice is left as an exercise to the reader.)

Comment: Thank you so much. Twas really silly of me to access the filehandle twice, and forget about the trailing newline too! As for the regular expression, yes - I now understand that mine was indeed dicey. The single spaces around the = sign are specified, though - but this comes in as excellent feedback for my next code. 

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $line = "";
my $app = "";

print "Enter the app";
$app = <STDIN>;
print $app;
open my $fh, '<', "eg.txt" or die "Cannot open $!";
my @line = <$fh>;
my @fetch = map { /COMP\d+\s\=\s(\..\/\..\/.*)/g  } @line ;
$, = "\n";
print @fetch;
```

and then please send your response.

Comment: you are hardcoding COMP, That could be anything.

Comment: I perceived the app name as COMP

Comment: I get what you're doing, and I think it's a nice approach - but hardcoding wouldn't do for me, as I have a large number of application names that aren't "COMP"s, too. Hence, I do have to take that as an input from the user.

Thank you for the help!